# How to read two different List types from a binary file

Tags: java, list, file-io

I am trying to read two different lists from a binary file. One list is of type **Flight** and the other is of type **Customer**. I tried to use **instanceof** operator but the compiler shows error as 
***Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type List. Use the form List instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime.***
As the items have to be read using a loop until all the lists are read, I'm not sure how to implement this logic.
My code is as follows:

```
public static void readFromFile() throws Exception {
    List<Flight> flightList;
    List<Customer> customerList;

    //Create new input stream object
    objInStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileLocation));

    //Check if file exists
    if(!fileLocation.exists()) {
        //create new file
        fileLocation.createNewFile();
    }
    Object o;
    while((o = objInStream.readObject()) != null) {
        //Compiler shows error
        if(o instanceof List<Flight>) 
            flightList = (List<Flight>) o;
        else if(o instanceof List<Customer>)
            customerList = o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot check if `o` is a "list of ***_*__*_***."  You can check if the elements of `o` are *_*_, though.  Or you could just mark it explicitly.

But this is a normal consequence of type erasure.  Generics are only a *compile-time annotation*.  Your program will not keep the generics at runtime!

Answer (score 3):

when you declare generic type, you can get it.
when you use generic type, it will be erased.
eg:

```
public class Generics {
    public <T> T m1(T object){
        return object;
    }
    public void m2(){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
    }
}
```

decompilation: m1() deckare generic type, you can  get it from class file. m2() use generic type,erased.

```
public <T extends java/lang/Object> T m1(T);
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=2, args_size=2
     0: aload_1
     1: areturn
  LineNumberTable:
    line 20: 0
Signature: #15                          // <T:Ljava/lang/Object;>(TT;)TT;

public void m2();
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1
     0: new           #2                  // class java/util/ArrayList
     3: dup
     4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
     7: astore_1
     8: aload_1
     9: iconst_1
    10: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    13: invokeinterface #5,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    18: pop
    19: return
  LineNumberTable:
    line 24: 0
    line 25: 8
    line 26: 19
```

---